# Accessing Joined Tables in Linq2SQL When Returning IQueryable

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a linq query which draws a data set out of a database, but unfortunately due to the legacy nature of the database it requires a manual "join" to be enacted as part of the query.

Now I need to add further optional filters to the data set, some of which rely on the joined table - if I return the data set from the first query as a .AsQueryable() how do I go about accessing the joined table, as it doesn't seem to be available from the IQuerable?

Example:

```
var myQuery = (from o in db.FirstTable
                   join t in db.SecondTable on o.SecondID equals t.ID
                   select o).AsQueryable();

// (optional - if statement excluded for brevity)
myQuery = from x in myQuery where t.SomeField.Equals("My Filter Value");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whichever properties you need out of the table, you have to grab in the select. So, change your select from "select o" to "select o.Property1, o.Property2, t.Property1, t.Property2"